# I dont fix this error when make rtl8821ce!

Tags: wireless, 18.04, debugging

This is error (initialization from incompatible pointer type):
[image: initialization from incompatible pointer type]

Comment: Where did you download the package you are trying to compile? May we see the link? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and it is most likely based on the download.

Try the newest version I think [here](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce), and then run `make` and `sudo make install` after cd'ing to the download folder (after extracting the zip). The make command should work.